# How many square feet a FooFoo can wander?

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help with this? I got a wrong answer.

Problem: Joe's French poodle, FooFoo, is tied to the corner of the barn which measures 40 x 30. FooFoo's rope is 50 long. In terms of π, over how many square feet can FooFoo wander?

[image]

Comment: Another question with essentially no context? "I got a wrong answer" isn't really much to go on.

Comment: I just clicked because I wanted to see what is a FooFoo.

Comment: Good use of illustration! Without the image, I would have assumed the poodle was inside the barn, ashamed of what Joe made the dog groomer do to her fur (as poodles may look silly, they are pretty smart as dogs go) -- in which case $\pi$ would be irrelevant. If inside the barn, the rope is long enough to reach everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The picture above shows the limits that FooFoo can turn. It is then easy to compute our answer

$$\dfrac{3}{4} 50^2 \pi+\dfrac{1}{4}10^2 \pi  + \dfrac{1}{4}20^2 \pi = 2000 \pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If there weren't a building in the way, it would be a circle of radius $50$.  If FooFoo is left of the right wall of the building and above the bottom wall, the rope will be flat against the right wall, reducing its effective length.  You should get an area that is parts of three circles.  If you show your reasoning, we can find the error, but without that, we can't